# magento2 custom page layout

Tags: magento2

How to apply custom page layout template once the blocks are generated in magento 2x

Below is for magento1x

```
if ($settings->getPageLayout())
{
   $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayout());
}
```

Comment: from where you try to apply?

Comment: im trying to get the design settings like      $category = $this->_initCategory();                                     $settings = $this->_catalogDesign->getDesignSettings($category);   So this is how it is done in  magento1...wanted to know how in magento2